# edit.php didnt work and no notification / error show

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with the editing data on uploaded to MySQL. I am trying to edit the name file and the descryption,but there is no data shown on the form,
here my edit.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="homeadmin.php">Kembali</a> 

<table border=1>



<tr>
    <td align=center>Edit Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
      <?php
      include "dbconfig.php";

      error_reporting(E_ALL); 

      $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
      $mysql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads WHERE id=$id";
      $result = mysql_query($mysql);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      echo mysql_error();
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="update.php?">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php  echo "$row[id]"?>">
        <tr>        
          <td>Nama File</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="file" 
        size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[file]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Deskripsi</td>
          <td>
            <textarea input type="text" name="dekripsi"
            value="<?php echo "$row[dekripsi]"?>"> </textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>


     <td align="right">
            <input type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="Update">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i cant get the data from what i choose, its blank form, but when i try to change the query to :

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads WHERE id";
```

it get the data in the form, but not from what i choose, from the first `id` on the table (i choose the 3 id from the table) this should be fill with the data from what i choose.

Comment: I see your ID field is quoted in the query; is it declared as varchar?

Comment: no it is declared as int, why?

Comment: `WHERE id='$id'` I don't understand why is it wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Do you understand that `$file` is an array?

Comment: iam sorry to reply now, because my internet connection issue, @GrafiCode Studio and then what should i do? could you more specified? iam newbie on php and mysql,

Comment: Where is the `if (isset($_POST)`  and the `$_POST` of Submit button?

Comment: @edmhar, i use this code to other class and its succesfully without that, but in this class i just copy this code from other class to this class, and just change the row like `$row[file]` , but in here, it didnt work,

Comment: try to put `echo "aaa";` above `$_POST['id']`

Comment: i think the problem is, it cant get id, why it cant get the id?

Comment: @edmhar i've trying that and it didnt show the echo, whats the problem?

Comment: change `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
  $mysql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads WHERE id='$id'";` to   `$mysql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];`

Comment: I think the submit button? Can you show where is your `POST` Submit?

Comment: Few tips, Change Mysql to Prepared Functions. (mysqli or pdo) And another thing is `<input type="textarea" name="dekripsi" size="40" value="<?php echo "$row[dekripsi]"?>">` is not required and I don't see it working. `<textarea id="dekripsi" name="dekripsi" size="40"><?php echo $row['dekripsi']; ?></textarea>`

Comment: I would also try a different way for my update `$mysql = "UPDATE tbl_uploads SET file=".$file.", dekripsi=".$dekripsi." WHERE id=".$id."";` While I don't recommend mysql. Remember; it's leaving soon.

Comment: @Edmhar i already edit the post, the proble is the edit.php before redirect to update.php because i cant get the data on the form.

Comment: @MorganGreen yes thanks for the advise, but in this case i just start learning about php and mysql (newbie bro), and before i just found about mysql, next time i will learn about mysqli and pdo, 
i already edit my post, the problem is on the edit.php before go to update.php, because i cant get the data from the table on the form.

Comment: Do you have like this?  `<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >`

Comment: @Edmhar yes thats the problem what i miss, thanks bro, now the form of `nama file` is fill, but the form of dekripsi is still blank, any clue again?could you answer my question? not in comment, so i can give mark as accepted to your answer,

Comment: @John  I understand being new, but ultimately by learning mural_connect functions you're learning something of no use then moving forward to learn something else, I'd be more beneficial t learn supported functions then start from scratch, not trying to sound rude just my two cents

Comment: oke thank you @MorganGreen, i'l do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to have a `href` that getting the `ID`: 
Here is a sample code:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
```

for your `dekripsi` ,  is this the name of the column in your table?

Comment: thanks @Edmhar.
it solved bro, before i miss a character on the query.
thanks alot.

Comment: @John: No Problem, Happy Coding!